# Export CSV file in ServiceNow using URL containing personalized list columns

Tags: list, csv, url, servicenow

I'm trying to export a CSV file in ServiceNow using the URL. I've applied my various filters and I've personalized the list columns I need. The problem is, when I use the URL to obtain the records, I get ALL the columns and not my personalized list columns. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

The URL I'm using is as follows (sample, not the real URL):
https://abc.service-now.com/incident_list.do?sysparm_query=xyz

Can someone guide me as to whats missing in the URL?

Answer (score 2):

There's a URL parameter `sysparm_view` that you can add to specify the name of the view you want to use, but it sounds like you may still be missing something.

There's a difference between "Personalizing" a list layout and "Configuring" a list layout:

- The former ("personalizing") is a layout that is visible only to you.
  There's no way to give a URL to someone that will give them that
  particular list layout.
- The latter ("configuring") is what you'll
  need to use to define list layout configuration that is accessible to
  any user, and which can be targeted via the `sysparm_view` URL
  parameter

This wiki article defines views: 
http://wiki.servicenow.com/?title=View_Management#Creating_Views

If you follow the steps in "Creating Views", you'll end up with a view name (as specified by you when you created it, say you called it `kage77`. Then you'd be able to send someone a URL with `sysparm_view=kage77` and they'd see the list layout you associated with that view:

https://abc.service-now.com/incident_list.do?sysparm_query=xyz&sysparm_view=kage77

Comment: Thanks @Joey, I figured it out, all I had to do was create a report with the filters and the personalized list and use that URL, which gave me the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the file type as well like CSV/ XLSX/PDF

```
https://instance.service-now.com/incident_list.do?CSV
you can add few parameters,
&sysparm_query=active=true
&sysparm_fields=number%2Cshort_description
&sysparm_orderby=sys_id
```

More reference: https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/london-platform-administration/page/administer/exporting-data/task/t_ExportDirectlyFromTheURL.html